# is there a specific query to find the trigger_owner and constraint_owner in postgressql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

for example :-
Trigger name can be derived from pg_trigger but that trigger could be created by some other user who has access and could have created the trigger.
Similar issues for constraint_name .
For table emp(
user_id varchar(20),
emp_name varchar(20),
emp_salary integer);
Suppose user1 creates this table and user2 creates trigger and constraint name.
So is there a way to know who created trigger and constraint name because in the pg_trigger table and information_schema.columns will show user1 as trigger_owner and table owner.

Answer (score 1):

A trigger is not something that is associated with PostgreSQL's system of permissions, and therefore there is no need to record the creator/owner of a trigger.  The same applies for constraints on a table.  Procedures/functions require permissions so that a DBA can limit who calls/runs the procedure; a trigger is merely something that calls a procedure when a change is made to a table (and therefore essentially anyone with write access to the table should have access to fire the trigger).

While ownership is really only relevant when it comes to permissions, if you want to know the creator for auditing purposes, I would recommend that you use the `%u` flag in `log_line_prefix` and set `log_statement = ddl` or `log_statement = all` so that you can see which user created the trigger/constraint.